# how can I get the checkbox checked Item from grid using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

I have got two kendo ui grids (parent grid , child grid) and i have got check box column on parent grid if i click on the checkbox in row in grid, I need to get the corresponding row data and i need to do moving that selected row data to another grid when click on button for that    I have implemented button clikc like this ...

For that purpose I have done like this ....

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('#btnMove').click(function() {

            ('#GridParent').on("click", "td", function (e) {
                var selectedTd = $(e.target).closest("td");
                var grdChkBox = selectedTd.parents('tr').find("td:first").next("td").find('input:checkbox');
                //grdChkBox.prop('checked', !grdChkBox.prop('checked'));
                if(grdChBox.Checked)
                {
                   // here I need to get the checkbox selected item row data 
                  // i dont know it is the correct way to get the item pls correct me                                                                  
                }   

            var sourcegrid =  $('#GridParent').data('kendoGrid');
            var destinationgrid =  $('#ChildGrid').data('kendoGrid');

            var checkeditem =                        
            });       
</script>
@model IEnumerable<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.StudentDetails>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoSampleMVCApp.Models.StudentDetails>()    
    .Name("GridParent")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentclass).HeaderTemplate("<input id='selectall' class='chkbx' type='checkbox' onclick='ToggleChkBox(this.checked);' />").ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Sortable(false).Filterable(false).Width(30);
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentId).Filterable(false).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentName).Filterable(false).Width(90);
        columns.Bound(p => p.StudentBranch).Filterable(false).Width(90);

    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:250px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("Orders_Read", "StudentDtls"))
     )
  )

 <input id="btnMove" type="button" value="Move" />
  // second grid .......
```

I am not sure about the data how can i get when the check box selected

would any one pls help on this ...
 Many Thanks .....

Comment: where is your `btnMove` i don't see in your code.

Comment: any other way i can get this ....

Comment: any one have any idea how to do this..

Comment: you have to bind this data in another grid right? on button click.

Comment: yes but only selected rows i need to bind the data in button click event  ....I am not able to get the checked row value for this .....

Comment: hi just bind selected `checkbox` data in div not in grid.But not in button click. ijust done in checkbox check.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34833/discussion-between-jaimin-and-pratap-k)

Comment: @Jaimin i am in chat .......

Comment: @Jaimin u der I have posted code in the chat.,...

Comment: check my code. grid is bind from controller side.

Answer (score 0):

In `checkbox` check select row bind in new `grid` from controller side. Hope it's working for you

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GridListView";
}
<h2>
    GridListView</h2>
<script src="~/Script/Jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Script/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Script/kendo.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Script/kendo.web.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Script/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="~/Content/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Content/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#grid12').on("click", ".chkbxq", function (e) {
            var selectedTd = $(this).is(':checked');

            var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
            var cellIndex = $(this).parent().parent().index();
            var grid = $("#grid12").data("kendoGrid");
            var datatItem = grid.dataItem(grid.tbody.find('tr:eq(' + cellIndex + ')'));

            if (selectedTd == true) {
                sampleItem = datatItem.SampleItems;
                sampleCode = datatItem.SampleCode;
                sampledescription = datatItem.SampleDescription;

                datavalueitem = sampleItem + "--" + sampleCode + "--" + sampledescription;

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("NewGridView", "Test")',
                    type: "Post",
                    data: { sampleItem: sampleItem, sampleCode: sampleCode, sampledescription: sampledescription },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        debugger;
                        $("#mygrid").val(null);
                        var customDataList = $('#grid');
                        customDataList.empty();
                        customDataList.append(result.Data);
                        customDataList.append(result.Data);

                          $("#divasd").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: result,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: true
                        },
                        columns: [
                       {
                            field: "SampleDescription",
                            width: 90,
                        }, {
                            field: "SampleCode",
                            width: 90,
                        }, {
                            width: 100,
                            field: "SampleItems"
                        }
                    ]
                    });

                    }
                });
            }


        });

    });
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("GridListView", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
{ 

    <input id="Submit1" type="button" value="SubmitValue" />
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TwoModelInSinglePageModel.SampleModel>()
    .Name("grid12")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentclass).HeaderTemplate("<input id='selectall' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />").ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleDescription);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleCode);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleItems);
    })
        .AutoBind(true) // here I am disabling automatic binding at page load
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Test"))
     )
  )

    <br />

    <div id="divasd">
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
   public JsonResult NewGridView(string sampleItem, string sampleCode, string sampledescription)
        {

            List<SampleModel> sampleAddList = new List<SampleModel>();
             SampleModel sampleAdd = new SampleModel();
            sampleAdd.SampleCode = sampleCode;
            sampleAdd.SampleDescription = sampledescription;
            sampleAdd.SampleItems = sampleItem;

            sampleAddList.Add(sampleAdd);
            var result = sampleAddList;  


            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

This bind grid from `Controller side`

**Model**

```
  public class SampleModel
    {
        public bool studentclass { get; set; }
        public string SampleDescription { get; set; }
        public string SampleCode { get; set; }
        public string SampleItems { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: many thanks your support, can I include another kendo ui grid in side of these Divs  `<div id="divasd">
    </div>`

Comment: one more question , I would like to ask you, what is meant by WebGrid( it it equal to Kendo UI grid) because I need to use same type of grid(kendo UI grid) for both grids

Comment: i think Web grid is completely different from kendo ui Grid if this is correct , I am not able to use your code.....

Comment: i just want to check the whether the row is checked or not and if it is checked i need to get the checked row value see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072075/checkbox-is-always-coming-as-unchecked?noredirect=1#comment26447498_18072075

Comment: i m sorry we need to use mvc wrapper for both grids , i am not able find the solution  in getting check box checked item ..

Comment: pls check above link, i ma not able get that checked item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072075/checkbox-is-always-coming-as-unchecked